# Rails: ActiveRecord and send; how do I set an activerecord instance's relation with only knowing the class names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

So I'm iterating through all my AR's and setting their relationships dynamically...so I know that I have SomeObject and that it belongs_to ManyObjects...I want to do something like this:

```
an_object.some_relation = related_object
an_object.save
```

Is there a way to do this through **send** or some similar such method? This of course doesn't work:

```
an_object.send(some_relation_name, related_object)
```

This works, I'm just interested in doing it a less dangerous, more Rails-meta way:

```
an_object.update_attributes({"#{some_relation_name}_id"=>related_object.id})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well you could do

```
an_object.send("#{some_relation_name}=", related_object)
```

Which is just dynamically calling the setter method.

Or you could go a little lower level and use :

```
an_object.reflect_on_association(some_relation_name).build_association(related_object_attributes)
```

I'd go with the first, it's a little "scary" to use send sometimes, but that's what ruby is all about, dynamic programming.

Comment: Perfect...I haven't always grasped that the = symbol can be part of the literal name of the setter

Comment: ```reflect_on_association``` is a class method.